# Creating a java7 JVM with the JNI invocation API

Tags: c++, java-native-interface, java-7

We have a class in java 7 and need to load it from native code. I have already used java 6 with JNI but java 6 can't load that class. So I installed the new JDK, changed include directories and link references in my VC project etc. All was well until I wanted to start the jre7 from JNI:

**JNI_CreateJavaVM** takes the the java version in **vm_args.version** parameter but there's no definition for a newer version than 1.6.

```
JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
...
vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
vm_args.nOptions = 2;
vm_args.options = options;
vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = 0;

int ret = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
```

Calling `FindClass` for the java7 class obviously produces an *UnsupportedClassVersionError*.

**The problem:** How do I create a java7 JVM with `JNI_CreateJavaVM`?

Comment: Are you sure that your program is actually creating a Java 7 VM (i.e. the dynamic library that it loads references a Java 7 JRE)?

Comment: @themel There is no `JNI_VERSION_1_7` constant like `JNI_VERSION_1_6` so he can't create a java7 JVM, only a java6 JVM. That's the problem.

Comment: Since `JNI_VERSION_1_6 = 0x00010006`, could you try `vm_args.version = 0x00010007` to see what happens?

Comment: Yes, the references are set to Java 7 JRE, I'm uninstall older jre to certify...

Comment: Again, is corretly, the JNI_VERSION_1_7 constant doesn't exists.

Comment: iccthedral, I already tried this... but doesn't work...

Comment: This has nothing to do with the JNI version - there is no new version of the JNI, so no need to recompile your program. You just need to make sure that you're actually using a Java 7 runtime when you try to load Java 7 classes. Equivalently, there is no JNI_VERSION_1_5, but you could still use Java 5 with JNI...

Comment: RFas, How did you solve the problem? Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem are on path environment variable, that's refers to jre6 before jre7.
On visual C++->Property Pages->Debugging->Environment, I changed to:
path=C:\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Java\jre7\bin\client;%path%

Or directly on: My Computer->Properties->Advanced->Environment Variables

Comment: The cause was in the User Environment Variables, that sets the path to the jre6, preceding my settings when runs the application. I had checked the System environment, but had forgotten the User environment.

Answer (score 2):

For Mac users, I highly recommend to read this article:

How do I switch between Java 7 and Java 6 on OS X 10.8.2? 
https://superuser.com/questions/490425/how-do-i-switch-between-java-7-and-java-6-on-os-x-10-8-2

I successfully compiled and ran the JNI example in which I call some static methods from a Java class I created. I solved the problem by invoking "java_home" like this:

/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.6.0_45 --exec javac Sample.java